# Usamos verbo ou substantivo: "carreteiros em viajem" ou "carreteiros em viagem"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, verbos, sintaxe, substantivos

Na frase abaixo, devemos usar o substantivo ***viagem*** ou o verbo ***viajem***?

"Carreteiros em **viajem**" ou "Carreteiros em **viagem**" ?

Tem uma regra que diz que é para usar com a letra **J** quando é verbo, então nesse caso eu tenho um sujeito na terceira pessoa do plural (carreteiros) fazendo uma ação **viajar** ou **em viajem**. Seria o mesmo que dizer "Soldados **em guerra**" onde o **em** está ligando um verbo **guerrear**.

Gostaria de outras opiniões a respeito desse caso em específico.

Comment: Isso depende do contexto. Contextualiza os exemplos em frase de exemplo.

Comment: Oi @JorgeB. o contexto é o seguinte: Tenho uma lista de motoristas que estão viajando,esses são motoristas de caminhões, os chamados "carreteiros" e no titulo desta lista eu Coloquei "Carreteiros em viajem" porque é uma ação que eles estão fazendo, mas falaram que esta errado a grafia, dai fiquei na dúvida

Comment: `guerra` não é uma forma do verbo guerrear, é um substantivo.

Comment: @Centaurus O perguntador sabe que a flexão do verbo viajar _viajem_ se escreve com _j_, e, imagino, que o substantivo _viagem_, com _g_, que é o que é tratado na outra pergunta. A sua dúvida, por muito curioso que possa parecer, é se a expressão correta é  _carreteiros em viagem_ (com _em_ + substantivo) ou _carreteiros em viajem_ (_em_ + verbo). Portanto é uma questão diferente, mais de gramática do que ortografia. A outra questão é exclusivamente ortográfica.

Comment: @Jacinto   Não entendo o uso de um verbo após a preposição "em".  Carreteiros em viagem, turistas em trânsito, pedestres em circulação... não vejo como usar um tempo verbal em tal construção gramatical.

Comment: @Centaurus Tens razão: _em_ seguido de verbo não faz sentido (talvez se o verbo estiver no gerúndio, mas no conjuntivo não). Mas é essa a dúvida colocada na questão, e foi essa dúvida que as duas respostas tentaram esclarecer. A troca de comentários após a minha resposta ajuda a clarificar isso.

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: [Is this question a duplicate?](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/182/are-this-question-a-duplicate)

Comment: @Math Creio que o OP quis dizer "_eu tenho um sujeito na terceira pessoa do plural (carreteiros) fazendo uma ação viajar o**u** em viajem_." Ou seja, escreveu **o** onde deveria ter escrito **ou**. Manter o _em viajem_ na mesma frase dá sentido à referência anterior à _terceira pessoa do plural_.

Comment: SneepSNinjA, talvez te tenhas apercebido do alvoroço em torno da tua pergunta. Umas pessoas pensaram que era uma dupicata (igual a outra que já existia), outras pessoas pensaram que não, teve que ir a votos, e venceu (e convenceu) a opinião que não era duplicata. Entretanto para tornar a pergunta mais clara eu e o @Math alteramos umas coisinhas, e mudámos o título (que era de facto igual ao título da outra.  Mas é a tua pergunta, portanto se as mudanças não forem do teu agrado muda o que quiseres, ou diz-nos que nós simplesmente pomos como estava. (Reparei agora que estavas há pouco no site.)

Comment: @Jacinto ao meu ver a pergunta agora esta mais clara, esta relacionada a outra que quase caiu na duplicidade mesmo, mas como podem ver a dúvida é outra, mas o exemplo usado foi o mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Eu nunca achei que elas fossem iguais, e acho que agora já todos entenderam isso.

Comment: @tchrist You had removed the tag *gramática* and added *ortografia*. I suppose this was during that retagging spree of yours. You may have missed [this discussion](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/182/is-this-question-a-duplicate), where, after the question was closed as duplicated and reopened, we established that the question was about grammar, not orthography. Comments above make the same point. So I removed orthography, and added *sintaxe*. I guess it's a bit more precise than grammar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Definitivamente **carreteiros em viagem**. *Viagem* nessa frase é um substantivo, é **a** viagem que eles estão fazendo, e não uma forma do verbo viajar. O verbo poder-se-ia usar, por exemplo em **espero que os carreteiros viajem bem**.

É a mesma coisa com **soldados em guerra**. *Guerra* é um substantivo, é **a** guerra em que os soldados estão a combater. Com o verbo poderia ser **os soldados guerreiam** ou **espero que os soldados guerreiem com coragem**.

Comment: Ou seja, em *soldados em guerra*, "guerra" não é uma conjugação verbal, certo?

Comment: Claro que não. Existe _ele guerreia, eu guerreio_, mas não _ele guerra_.

Comment: Obrigado, o que me confunde é que o verbo é a ação do sujeito, e o sujeito na frase é o carreteiro e a ação "parece" ser mas não é a tal da viagem, mas com o exemplo similar da guerra ficou bem claro agora, realmente não da p/ conjugar "eu guerra, ele guerra"

Comment: @SneepSNinjA A questão é que _carreteiros em viagem_ não tem verbo. Vê na outra resposta. Para ter verbo teria de ser _carreteiro estão em viagem_ (o verbo é _estão_) ou _carreteiros andam em viagem_ (o verbo é _andam_). A viagem é a "coisa" onde os carreteiro estão, mesmo que não esteja lá o verbo _estar_. É muito difícil meter um **em** entre o sujeito e o verbo.

Comment: Sim agora entendi

Answer (score 9):

A segunda forma.

Explicação: "viajem" é a terceira pessoa do conjuntivo (subjuntivo) do verbo viajar: [que eles viajem](http://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-viajar/). No exemplo, poderia ser "carreteiros **viajam**", no presente do indicativo, ou "carreteiros fazendo (ou a fazer) uma viagem", usando o gerúndio (ou infinitivo) do verbo fazer e o **substantivo** "**viagem**", ou simplesmente "carreteiros em **viagem**".

*Acrescentado*. Relativamente a "soldados em **guerra**", também a palavra "guerra" é,  como já foi salientado, um substantivo e não uma forma verbal.